# Delete first four lines from the top in content stored in a variable

Tags: php, lines

I have a variable that needs the first four lines stripped out before being displayed:

```
Error Report Submission
From: First Last, email@example.com, 12345
Date: 2009-04-16 04:33:31 pm Eastern

The content to be output starts here and can go on for any number of lines.
```

I need to remove the 'header' from this data before I display it as part of a 'pending error reports' view.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Mmm. I am sure someone is going to come up with something nifty/shorter/nicer, but how about:

```
$str = implode("\n", array_slice(explode("\n", $str), 4));
```

If that is too unsightly, you can always abstract it away:

```
function str_chop_lines($str, $lines = 4) {
    return implode("\n", array_slice(explode("\n", $str), $lines));
}

$str = str_chop_lines($str);
```

**EDIT**: Thinking about it some more, I wouldn't recommend using the `str_chop_lines` function unless you plan on doing this in many parts of your application. The original one-liner is clear enough, I think, and anyone stumbling upon `str_chop_lines` may not realize the default is 4 without going to the function definition.

Comment: I believe your first example is easier to glance over and understand it's meaning quicker than other 1 line solutions. 'plus uno' :P

Comment: Yeah, at first I thought it was ugly but it's pretty clear on what it does, I think.

Comment: add the extra "limit" parameter to the explode function for more efficiency: explode("\n", $str, 5)

Answer (score 4):

`$content = preg_replace("/^(.*\n){4}/", "", $content);`

Answer (score 2):

Strpos helps out a lot: Here's an example:

```
// $myString = "blah blah \n \n \n etc \n \n blah blah";

$len = strpos($myString, "\n\n"); 
$string = substr($myString, $len, strlen($myString) - $len);
```

$string then contains the string after finding those two newlines in a row.

Comment: Have you tested this? It it not working me, strpos returns the position of the first occurrence, not whatever comes after.

Comment: Sorry about that - edited my post to do it a different way and left out the part that actually did it!

Comment: Have you tested _this_? :) It's not working either. I'm not sure why, though.

Comment: Yeah - http://www.kanago.net/loltest.php and the same .phps has it. The commented out string actually has spaces between newlines unlike the actual string. Oopsies. Embarrass me enough yet? :D

Comment: Haha, just looking out. :) I wasn't testing it with the string you gave, though, it isn't working on my machine with the string the OP gave. Odd. *Shrug*

Answer (score 1):

Split the string into an array using `split(rex)`, where `rex` matches two consecutive newlines, and then concatenate the entire array, except for the first element (which is the header).